# RSACryptoServiceProvider.SignHash with SHA256 returns 128 bytes instead of 32?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography

I'm new to cryptography, so perhaps I'm confused on what should happen here. I start with a 32 byte message digest and attempt to sign it using my private key. The output of RSA.SignHash is a 128 bytes. I am expecting 32.

```
    static private byte[] RSAHashAndSignData(byte[] data, RSAParameters privateKey)
    {
        byte[] signedHash;
        //Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider.
        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            //Import the public key 
            RSA.ImportParameters(privateKey);

            //Encrypt the passed byte array
            var sha = SHA256Managed.Create();
            var digest = sha.ComputeHash(data);
            signedHash = RSA.SignHash(digest, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
        }

        return signedHash;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am expecting 32.

That is an incorrect assumption. Signing does not produce a size equal to the size of the input.

Using PKCS#1 padding, using a 1024-bit RSA key will produce as 128-byte signature. The size of a signature is related to the size of the modulus of the signing key.

Comment: Thanks, that makes tons of sense.

Comment: To be precise, the signature is of the exact same size as the modulus in bytes, regardless of the padding (except maybe for textbook RSA where the output is a number smaller than the modulus, not an octet string). And the modulus is - by definition - the same as the key size for RSA.

Comment: Also please use RSA-2048 or higher if you have the option. Industries have been moving away from 1024-bit keys.